# How do I use an <input>'s pattern attribute to require at least one usable character?

Tags: regex, html, forms

I've got an `<input>` searchbox, and I want to add `pattern` to guide the user to submitting more than just whitespace. The `required` attribute doesn't let them submit an empty string, but searching for a couple of spaces goes through and isn't useful.

I've tried the following, but input such as "`a couple of keywords`" isn't valid with them:

- `pattern="\S+"`
- `pattern="(!\s*)"`
- `pattern="(\s*\S\s*){,}"`

I know the `^` and `$` symbols are implied, and adding them doesn't change anything in the results.

**How do I write a pattern that matches every input except white space without any other characters?**

Comment: try `pattern="[^ \"]+"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Fails on the input `some words` (even when I fixed the quoting error)

Comment: try `pattern="(?! +\")[^\"]+"` or `pattern="[^\"]*[^ \"][^\"]*"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj that does appear to work. If you would be so kind as to explain how/why, I'd be happy to accept the answer.

Comment: Hey, in what browser are you trying this out? Are you sure it supports the pattern attr?

Comment: @Tigt which one you mean? did you try `.*\S.*` ? does your input contain double quotes?

Comment: @Harvtronix Windows Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 m. Firefox has been producing the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below regexes.

```
pattern = ".*\S.*"
```

or

```
pattern = ".*[^ ].*"
```

So this regex asserts that there must be atleast one non-space character present in the input string. `.*` matches any character zero or more times. `[^ ]` negated character class which matches any character but not of a space. Since `[^ ]` matches also a tab character, adding also the tab character `[^ \t]` inside the char class would be better.

Comment: The first one seems like it'll catch other forms of whitespace and is a little shorter, so that's the one I went with. Thanks a bunch!