# HTML form validation pattern, must have at least 1 letter

Tags: html, forms, validation

My form field is for users to enter their first name, I want users to be allowed to put a space "billy bob", but MUST require a letter.

My code:
    `pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+"`

This accepts, letters and spaces. How can I modify it to require the use of at least 1 letter. I want to avoid users entering a name that is all spaces.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use an <input>'s pattern attribute to require at least one usable character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112549/how-do-i-use-an-inputs-pattern-attribute-to-require-at-least-one-usable-chara)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
([a-zA-Z]+\s*)+
```

We're saying that we need at least 1 letter `[a-zA-Z]+` followed by zero or many spaces `\s*` and we repeat the whole thing one or many times `([a-zA-Z]+\s*)+`

The above will work if you don't want the name to start with spaces otherwise you can use:

```
 (\s*[a-zA-Z]+\s*)+
```

That's the same pattern but with zero or many leading spaces `\s*`

Answer (score 1):

I think this works for you.

It is only accept letter and spaces.

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]*$
```